# Sequelize join source model into target model

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

I have these models:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const Tool = sequelize.define('Tool', {
      Price:  {type: DataTypes.STRING(255)},
      PurchaseDate: DataTypes.DATE,
    });

  return Tool;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    const RepairOrder = sequelize.define('RepairOrder', {
      OrderNumber: {type: DataTypes.STRING(255)}
    }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate(models) {
          RepairOrder.belongsTo(models.Tool, {as: 'Tool'});
        }
      }
    });

  return RepairOrder;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Hammer = sequelize.define('Hammer', {
    Color: {type: DataTypes.STRING(255)}
  },
  {
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        Hammer.belongsTo(models.Tool, {as: 'Tool'});
      }
    }
  });

  return Hammer;
};

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Spanner = sequelize.define('Spanner', {
    Size: {type: DataTypes.STRING(255)}
  },
  {
    classMethods: {
      associate(models) {
        Hammer.belongsTo(models.Tool, {as: 'Tool'});
      }
    }
  });

  return Spanner;
};
```

Because of the belongsTo methods Hammer and Spanner have a ToolID column.
Now I want to receive all Repair Orders with the Tool information, so I join the tools into the Repair Orders.

```
RepairOrder.findAll({
  attributes: ['ID', 'OrderNumber'],
  include: [{
    model: Tool, as: 'Tool'   
  }]
});
```

But I also want to know which type(Hammer or Spanner) of tool it is when selecting the Repair Order, so how can I join both into the Tool?
 Something like

```
RepairOrder.findAll({
      attributes: ['ID', 'OrderNumber'],
      include: [{
        model: Tool, as: 'Tool',
        include: [{'JOIN ON "Hammer"."ToolID" = "Tool"."ID"'},
                  {'JOIN ON "Spanner"."ToolID" = "Tool"."ID"'}]
      }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot, with your present model definitions. You'll likely get an error message that Tool is not associated with Hammer (or Spanner).

So, you should modify your model definition as below:
In your **Tool** model, include the following associations:

```
Tool.hasMany(models.Hammer, {as: 'Tool'});
Tool.hasMany(models.Spanner, {as: 'Tool'});
```

After this, you can JOIN Tool on Hammer and Spanner in following way:

```
RepairOrder.findAll({
    attributes: ['ID', 'OrderNumber'],
    include: {
      model: Tool, as: 'Tool',
      include: [{
        model: models.Hammer,
        as: 'Tool'
      }, {
        model: models.Spanner,
        as: 'Tool'
      }]
    }
});
```